# Swagger UI display in production

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have integrated swagger with my rest api's for documentation. When I hit the URL `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`, I can see the swagger UI. But, when deployed to production and i hit URL `http://r***.com/swagger-ui.html`, I can not see the swagger UI. How to see it in production server also? I am very new to swagger.

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing when you are hitting production swagger URL ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I hit the IP address of the production server. The format is like `http://<ip-address-of-the-server>:<port-number>/swagger-ui.html`. But, still don't know why, it is not working when I hit domain address format.

Comment: You must have host mapping entry in you windows machine host file.

Answer (score 0):

Its like you have to serve your swagger-ui.html page as a static content. The URL that you are hitting is not pointing to the actual page on production server.